# How to use html datalist with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Given

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

How to apply bootstrap css to this? I would except just to add `class="form-control"` and it would be layouted in the same fasion as a select element? But that did not work. Is this tag not supported?

Comment: Even though this question aims at Bootstrap 4 I think it is useful to know that Bootstrap 5 now supports datalists: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I cannot confirm, that bootstrap 4 does generally not work with the `<input>`/`<datalist>` element. Basically you only apply the `select` field bootstrap classes to the `input` field, which then gets the look of a select/dropdown with input functionality, e.g.:

```
<input list="encodings" value="" class="col-sm-6 custom-select custom-select-sm">
<datalist id="encodings">
   <option value="ISO-8859-1">ISO-8859-1</option>
   <option value="cp1252">ANSI</option>
   <option value="utf8">UTF-8</option>
</datalist>
```

Looks like that on recent Firefox:

[image]

Comment: @Muleskinner The edit results in invalid markup and leads to inconsistency between code and the preview in the GIF

Answer (score 5):

Datalists are finally mentioned in Bootstrap 5. However, I am not sure this means they BS supports datalists. There are no special classes for them and an inconsistency note.
See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `datalist` tag is not supported in Bootstrap 4.

So, you'd have to add custom css if you want to use that.